# python selemium driver.execute_script()

Tags: javascript, python

I want to cancel all checkbox one time.
Use element.click() is ugly but it can work like this

```
allcan=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@type="checkbox"]')
for i in allcan:
    i.click()
```

So I try to use driver.execute_script() like this

```
allcan = 'var index = form1.no.value; \
            for (i=1;i<=index;i++){ \
                var rchk = document.getElementsByName("del_Y"+i)[0] \
                rchk.checked = false \
                ;}'
driver.execute_script(allcan)
```

That JavaScript can work in chrome console,but in python it show me

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)
```

I don't know why please help me.

Comment: Not sure the error is from that but you have to declare the iterator variable with a keyword `for (let i=1;i<=index;i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end this statement with semicolon.

```
var rchk = document.getElementsByName("del_Y"+i)[0];
```

This will get rid of `SyntaxError`, but as @Peterrabbit mentioned in the comment you need to pay attension to  `i` and `form1` as those variables are not defined. So most likely you will encounter with `Reference Error`.

Comment: But why it doesn't need to use semicolon in chrome console?